# Turn Log2 Iterativ into Recursiv way

Tags: java, recursion

I thought about a simple Task which is to calculate Log2 in an iterative way like:

```
public static int log2(int x) {
    int result = 0;

    while (x > 1) {
        x = x / 2;
        result++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now I want to turn this in a recursive function, but I think I overcomplicated it.

Ended like this:

```
public static int recLog2(int x) {
    if (x < 1) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return recLog2(x/2);
    }

}
```

The problem is I'm going one step too far and I can't figure out how to get the solution of it.

Example:

```
log2(13) -> 3
reclog2(13) -> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to accumulate value with every recursion level. Rough solution (I didn't check it for sort of off-by-one errors) could be:

```
if (x < 1) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return 1 + recLog2(x/2);
}
```

Seems like learning example so I left final solution to you. If it is for practical purposes, I recommend using expression built upon Java methods `Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(Integer.highestOneBit(x))` which is more concise and efficient.

Comment: Well, thanks for the hint. The Final Solution is looking like this: 
if (x < 1) {
    return -1;
} else {
    return 1 + recLog2(x/2);
}